# How to use a single view from the parent activity to each child activity without writing any code in child activity?

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

I want to have a same view in my each activity and want to perform the same task in each of my activity on that view. Also, I have a parent activity which is parent of every activity in my app.

One way to do that is to use the same code in each class and xml. But i don't want to copy past the same code in each class.

how can I use only the one view in my parent activity class and reflect same in each child activity.

Comment: Maybe you can use include, or merge, Stub

Answer (score 1):

You may use   tag to include the same view at different xml layout files. THis may come helpful in cases like you have to show a view/layout consistently in every screen of your application. So to avoid duplication you can try 'include'ing the layout in all layout files. Please find more information here:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: thanks noone for your answer. I can do that, But using this way too, I have to include the same layout in my all xmls. I need such a way, by which i dont have to include or write the same code in any of my activities except the parent one

Comment: Yes. you will have to use include tag to include same xml in all layouts. You may keep the java code in one place (may be in a base activity) though

Comment: Or one more approach.. you can use static fragments. in this case also you may need to add fragment in xml using <fragment/> tag.

Comment: I am using activities here, no need for fragments right now, Also, Isn't there any option by which i  don't have to write the same include tag in xmls or same code in the activities?